# R package importing package between two version numbers?

Tags: r, r-package

Is it possible to structure the Imports section of an R package description file such that a package between two version numbers is required? I assume the answer is no, but thought I would reach out to the StackOverflow community.

For background, my company has an internal R package that depends in large part on a separate publicly available package on CRAN (a niche one I won't name). Unfortunately, some recent changes in that dependency have introduced some serious new bugs, and until we can work with the maintainers to resolve all those, we want our internal package to use versions of that package before a certain version number (to avoid those new problems) and after a certain version number (to take advantage of more recent functions that have been added).

In practice, when i try something basic like this, this works fine, as you'd expect

```
Imports:
    somedependency(>= 1.4.3)
```

but anything like

```
Imports:
    somedependency(>= 1.4.3, < 2.0.0)
```

results in an error like

```
   Malformed Depends or Suggests or Imports or Enhances field.
   Offending entries:
        somedependency(>= 1.4.3, < 2.0.0)
   Entries must be names of packages optionally followed by '<=' or '>=',
   white space, and a valid version number in parentheses.
   
   See section 'The DESCRIPTION file' in the 'Writing R Extensions'
   manual.
```

That [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#The-DESCRIPTION-file) page doesn't seem to indicate this is possible, but I thought there might be some undocumented work around or a best practice for this situation (a check of the dependency package's version in the code itself on load?). Thanks!

Comment: You could check the version `.onLoad` using `packageVersion` and warn the user with a `packageStartupMessage` if the wrong version is installed. It might be best if the maintainer of the dependency provides the old version under a different name. `lme4` did that for some time when they removed functionality that many people were using.

Comment: Great tip! Yeah, currently using packageVersion in one of the functions but didn't know about .onLoad, great call. And i like that thought on providing an older version under a different name. Thanks!